# Twitter OAuth: users/search works but search/tweets does not

Tags: php, search, twitter, twitter-search

I want search for tweets in twitter. It is not working.

```
$parameters = array('q' => 'oauth');
$result = $connection->get('search', $parameters);
```

But when I do a user search it working perfectly.

```
$parameters = array('q' => 'oauth');
$result = $connection->get('users/search', $parameters);
```

I have also tried the below and that is also not working

```
$parameters = array('q' => 'oauth');
$result = $connection->get('search/tweets', $parameters);
```

What could be the reason?

Error message

```
stdClass Object
(
    [errors] => Array
        (
            [0] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [message] => Sorry, that page does not exist
                    [code] => 34
                )

        )

)
```

Comment: "It is not working" is NOT a valid explanation of your problem. Is there an error somewhere? What is the error message? Does it fail? Where? Does it produce a result? What are you expecting?

Comment: @Jocelyn Thank you very much much for your response. I have updated the post. Could you please help

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You seem to be using the library [TwitterOAuth](https://github.com/abraham/twitteroauth) by Abraham Williams.

I know this is an old question but I have just had the same problem as OP and it might keep happening to anyone else since apparently this library has not been updated for a while.

The problem seems to be that Twitter is no longer accepting requests via the version 1 of their API. You have to change the `$host` variable in the file `twitteroauth.php` as follows:

```
/* Set up the API root URL. */
//public $host = "https://api.twitter.com/1/";
public $host = "https://api.twitter.com/1.1/";
```